# Drupal, Ubercart products relating to blog articles and vice-versa

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, blogs, ubercart

I'm very new to drupal however what I'm trying to achieve I assumed would be relatively straightforward but finding any documentation on the subject is proving difficult.

I am creating an ecommerce site using ubercart, i have installed this and all of the relevant modules and have created custom product pages with not much hassle. What I need to do is create a 'blog' that's articles can relate to one or multiple products. I have managed to set up the blog with no issues but I am struggling to find out how I can first of all link the story to a product in the product creation process (i.e. when creating a product I can choose a blog article from a list to form a relationship). I have kind of managed to provide this required relationship using the References module. But I have no idea how I can use this relationship to, for instance dynamicall display a list of products related to the current blog article or vice-versa.

I have previously asked a similar question but an still unable to figure this out.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the field is attached to the `blog` content type then you'll have a list of related products automatically outputted in the field display. If you haven't, go to the 'Manage Display' section for that content type and make sure that field isn't hidden.

The References module is only uni-directional currently so you'd have to code a solution for the other way around yourself (not particularly tricky). Alternatively you could ditch References altogether and try the [Relation Module](http://drupal.org/project/Relation) which defines bi-directional relationships between entities.